# Sunburst chart, JavaScript open source (aka. ring chart, radial treemap, multi-level pie chart)

Tags: open-source, library, javascript, charts

A **sunburst chart** is a pie (or donut) chart in which each piece of pie is further split into smaller pieces. It is sometimes also called "sunburst partition":

[image: baobab]

Is there an open source JavaScript library that would allow me to display a multi-level pie chart?
Data would be sent by the server, for instance as JSON/JSONP.

Requirements:

- Display sunburst chart
- Open source
- Data must never be sent to any third-party (so no Google Charts)

Comment: How about [d3](http://d3js.org/)?

Comment: @John: You mean http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063423 I guess? It seems to require a bit of programming, but good find!

Comment: Yes, exactly. I does need quite a bit of programming, but so far d3 is the most versatile library for plotting diagrams of every kind.

Answer (score 4):

If you want a highly customized, open-source Javascript chart library, then [D3](http://d3js.org/) is a clear choice. It has been making the lives of visual artists and data scientists a lot easier with a diverse range of possibilities, along with ease of use.

Your example chart looks like the Sunburst chart to me. And here is the chart [re-created](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063423) in D3

[image]

And your data is definitely safe, as you wouldn't be dealing/interacting with third parties.

Another library worth mentioning is the [Highcharts.js](http://www.highcharts.com/); which is another wonderful visualizations open-source Javascript library.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fusher/abdPj/2/) for plotting a sunburst chart in Highcharts. And again, your data is completely safe and the library is open-source.